# Connecting 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a site that handles books, and in my database I want to have 2 tables, one for Books and one for Authors.

The problem is, that I want to have a column in the books that points to the author, so when a person views a book he could have a button to go to the author's page.

And probably the bigger problem:
In the authors' page I want to have a list of books by that author and the ability to click on each book to view it.

I don't know what data-type to associate with the coloumns and how to make them interact with each other.

I'd be happy to get an explaination, a guide or a good reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Books table:**

- id
- name
- author

**Authors table:**

- id
- name

Getting all Books including the author's name.

```
SELECT * FROM Books LEFT JOIN Auhtors ON Authors.id = Books.author
```

Getting all Books by a specific author:

```
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Author = $authorID
```

I think this is not that hard to understand, if you know basic SQL

Comment: Thank you all that answered! you all deserve a hug :D been much help.

Answer (score 2):

Using a relational DB, you'd put an authorID column in the Books table and configure that to be a foreign key into Authors table.

You'd get the author of a given book via a SQL join; you could also get all the Books via a SQL join as well.

Check out this PHP tutorial which addresses a similar case: http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqljoin/leftJoin.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Your database schema ...

### `books`

- **id** *INT*
- **title**  *VARCHAR*
- **author_id** *INT*

### `authors`

- **id** *INT*
- **name**  *VARCHAR*

---

The `author_id` field in the books table will correspond to the `id` field in the authors table. You would then do simple joins to combine the two and pull out the data you need ... The [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/left-join-optimization.html) is your friend in this endeavor, or here is [a simple RIGHT JOIN / LEFT JOIN tutorial](http://phpweby.com/tutorials/mysql/32).

Answer (score 0):

So you want a relation between the `books` table and the `authors` table?

What you do is set up your authors table with an author id as your primary key. Each row will then contain one author. In your `books` table you add columns for all necessary information about the book, including the author. The author column should here be an integer that will contain the id of the author listed in the `authors` table.

In addition to this you should make the author column, in the books table, a foreign key that points towards the `authors` table and id column.

When you want information regarding a book you'll use JOIN to connect both tables and give you information about the author aswell. This also goes for the profile of the author. You just specify a simple query on the books table to list out all books with the authors id.